# Question about computing the norm of linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $a = \{a_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ be inside $l_{\infty}$ where $l_{\infty}$ here is the sequences with supermum norm such that that norm is finite. Let $T : l_p \rightarrow l_p$ be defined as $Tx = \{x_na_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$. I am wondering what is the norm here ?

I think it is $||a||_{\infty}$.

$\|T\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1}  \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|} = \frac{\|x_na_n\|_p}{\|x_n\|_p}$. I think one has to use Cauchy-Schwarz here, but I am not sure how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and let $e(n)\in\ell^p$ be the sequence such that$$e(n)_k=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }k=n\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $\bigl\|e(n)\bigr\|_p=1$ and $\bigl|T\bigl(e(n)\bigr)\bigr|=|a_n|$. Therefore, $(\forall n\in\mathbb{n}):\|T\|\geqslant|a_n|$. Since this happens for each $n\in\mathbb N$, $\|T\|\geqslant\|a\|_\infty$.

On the other hand, if $\|x\|_p=1$, then$$\bigl|T(x)\bigr|=\sqrt[p]{\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_nx_n|^p}\leqslant\|a\|_\infty\sqrt[p]{\sum_{n=0}^\infty|x_n|^p}=\|a\|_\infty\|x\|_p.$$So, $\|T\|=\|a\|_\infty$.

Comment: Can you explain how do we get that inequality for the other hand case ?

Comment: @Newbie For each $n\in\mathbb N$, $|a_n|\leqslant\|a\|_\infty$.

Comment: But here we have the inequality which depends on sqrt though we don't have n isolated? $\bigl|T(x)\bigr|=\sqrt[p]{\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_nx_n|^p}\leqslant\|a\|_\infty\sqrt[p]{\sum_{n=0}^\infty|x_n|^p}=\|a\|_\infty\|x\|_p.$

Comment: @Newbie $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_nx_n|^p\leqslant\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\|a\|_\infty|x_n|\right)^p={\|a\|_\infty}^p\sum_{n=0}^\infty|x_n|^p$$amd therefore$$\sqrt[p]{\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_nx_n|^p}\leqslant\|a\|_\infty\sqrt[p]{\sum_{n=0}^\infty|x_n|^p}.$$

Comment: Sorry one last question how did you get the first inequality above ?

Comment: Do you mean the first inequality from my previous comment?

Comment: Yeah that precisely.

Comment: @Newbie Again, it's because $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):|a_n|\leqslant\|a\|_\infty$.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, my mistake I understand everything now thanks so much.